# Getting only the modified part of MS Excel Files in C#.Net Desktop Application

Tags: c#, excel

I want to sync ms excel file with my c# application. There are only three fields in xls file. The easiest way to do this could be to check the last modified date time and compare it with previous stored variable and if the file is modified reload the file, some other way(MD5 hashes compare) also described in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640023/how-to-check-if-a-file-has-been-modified-in-c-sharp)

But the problem is if the file grows too much. Then reading the whole file will be a wastage of resources in my case. And I need only the modified entries into excel file. It is possible? 
Can I obtain only the modified part of the excel file? (new record, or previous record deleted or updated)

If it is then how? Please help me, and if it is not possible then what will be the nearest solution to achieve this task. As I want to change the Google Calender entries according to excel file. 
Thanks

Comment: Is [change tracking](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-HP010342961.aspx) enabled in these excel docs?

Comment: This is a new thing for me. +1 I can enable this as excel file is on local machine. Can this help me in code?

Comment: You might check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337519/how-to-get-revisions-from-excel-or-powerpoint-files-in-c-sharp-using-interop)